# Android code for login in to soundcloud

Tags: android

i looking to get an android code for login in to soundcloud.com.I get an application from "https://github.com/soundcloud/android-intent-sharing". it is not ask to login when the user  try to share sound with out login..? ,
can you suggest me any helping tutorial.

Answer (score 1):

you are probably looking for [this](http://developers.soundcloud.com/docs), Android is using Java.

Comment: Thanks, But I am asking why sound cloud intent sharing sample "https://github.com/soundcloud/android-intent-sharing" not working if user is not logged in to the Sound Cloud application.